# How to convert between to case classes with `mostly the same` fields using Scala Shapeless

Tags: scala, generics, shapeless, hlist

Here I have to case classes which have mostly the same fields.

```scala
  final case class Id(id: String) // Param Class
  final case class Age(id: Id, age: Int) // Param Class

  final case class A(id: Id, data: Map[String, Any], age: Age) extends Presentable[A, APre] // Main Class 1
  final case class APre(id: String, data: Map[String, Any], age: Int) // Main Class 2
```

Here `A` and `APre` are my main classes.

Now I want to convert between this two class using Shapeless, so I write the following pseudo function:

```scala
trait Presentable[E, P] {
  def makePresentation[ET <: HList, PT <: HList](entity: E)(func : ET => PT)(implicit entGen: LabelledGeneric.Aux[E, ET], preGen: LabelledGeneric.Aux[P, PT]): P = {
    val entList = entGen.to(entity)
    preGen.from(func(entList))
  }
}
```

Here `func` is a mapper mapping the `HList` of `A` to `HList` of `APre` (or vice versa).

And I want to use the function like this:

```scala
  val age = Age(Id("age_1"), 18)
  val a = A(Id("id"), Map("tag1" -> "value1", "tag2" -> "value2"), age)

  val pre = a.makePresentation { entList =>
    entList.updateWith('id)((id: Id) => id.id).updateWith('age)((a: Age) => a.age)
  }
```

Here I can imply the mapping function myself. So I can convert any two case classes

So questions are:
1. How can I convert this two classes using shapeless?
2. In fact, I have tons of pairs of class like `A` to `APre`. So I want a `trait` to extract this convert function using generic. How to write this function?

Comment: I think you want to take a look at Chimney https://scalalandio.github.io/chimney/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disclaimer: I'm one of [chimney](https://github.com/scalalandio/chimney)'s authors.

In [earlier releases of chimney](https://github.com/scalalandio/chimney/tree/0.1.10) we implemented exactly what you are asking about - conversion between mostly identical case classes using shapeless.

I wouldn't recommend writing it by hand as there are some corner cases to consider (creating values if new object is missing some, transforming the fields that changed type/name, Java Beans, value classes, etc) and then you have to come up with how would you configure it, so if you need to have shapeless-bases solution look at the code from 0.1.10.

However, since 0.2.0, we rewritten the implementation into macros since if you had bigger case classes to transform (e.g. 12 fields or more) some derivations could compute several minutes(!) with no hope of improvement unless we dropped some of cases we support.

If you're just looking for a way of handling your transformations, then use newest chimney and call it a day.